# col-xs-6 bootstrap stacked as col-xs-12

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 with Wordpress and my columns are not working in my second row. I want them to be displayed as 2 divs in the same row. Instead they are stacked and I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. I'm just getting started and using internal styles in my header to make tweaks to my grid and get my layout down.

I'm running this on localhost using MAMP and Chrome. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code so far:

index.php

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bootstrap and WP</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<style>

.col-xs-12 {
      height: 50px;
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-xs-6 {
      height: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;
      color: black;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center; 
    }
  </style>
 </head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">.col-xs-12</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is correct and works fine, see http://www.bootply.com/mwS3GvdzCR . You must have something else other than this code

Comment: I'm wondering if my styles in my header are the problem maybe...Still not working for me.

Comment: Thanks for checkin it Fabio!

Comment: I tried adding those style to another external css but still can't get it to display properly.

Comment: Could WP be the problem?

Comment: What browser are you testing on? Try and change your .col-xs-6 width to 49.9% and see if that works? If it does then it maybe a browser issue. UPDATE: I see your using chrome - all the same amend the class to 49.9% to see what happens.

Comment: Also, try adding: -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Try to use the latest bootstrap version. Maybe there was a bug in 3.0 as we are now at 3.2

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I'm using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94 and it's up to date. I loaded bootstrap v3.2 and switched my width to 49.9% now at least my col-xs-6's are half the width but still remain stacked instead of inline. I haven't tried the "-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; " stuff yet.

Comment: I did try display: inline-block; - which was still stacked and display: inline; - which was 1/12th size but did display inline.

Comment: I was able to resolve this with floats and using the %'s. I don't think I should need to use the floats but hey it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Check the bootstrap.css file. I had the same problem with my col-xs-6 panels and the css files had `.col-xs-5,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-7` instead of `.col-xs-5,.col-xs-6,.col-xs-7`. All instances that should have been .col-xs-6 were .col-xs-12. Fix these in the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css files.